# Refreshing token for Connected app fails for user

Tags: connected-apps

My first attempt at someone (other than myself) using my connected app.  The connect worked fine - got accessToken/refreshToken, but by the time the user ran the token had expired so the refresh logic kicked in.  The refresh failed (java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token).

I noticed that my login always gets version=29, but this new user received version=30.  Do connected apps work "cross-version"?  Or do I somehow have to configure permissions?

How can I debug this?

Comment: This might be caused by using the token twice but I'm not entirely sure. Are you given a more descriptive error message when that happens?

Comment: What was in the body on your 400 response?